# How to share EFS among different ECS tasks and hosted in different instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, containers, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

Currently, the tasks that we defined are using `bind_mount` to share the EFS persistent data among containers in a single task, lets say `taskA` saves in `/efs/cache/taskA`.

But we are looking to find out, if there's any way to share the EFS data of `taskA` with the `taskB` containers in ECS. So `taskB` can be able to access data from `taskA` by doing `bind_mount` in `taskB`.

So can we use `bind_mount` in ecs to achieve this? or is there any alternative. Thanks

`taskB` definition looks like:

```
containerDefinitions": [
"mountPoints": [
        {
          "readOnly": null,
          "containerPath": "/efs/cache/taskA",
          "sourceVolume": "efs_cache_taskA"
        },
...],
"volumes": [
    {
      "fsxWindowsFileServerVolumeConfiguration": null,
      "efsVolumeConfiguration": null,
      "name": "efs_cache_taskA",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/efs/cache/taskA"
      },
      "dockerVolumeConfiguration": null
    },
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You no longer need to mount EFS on EC2 and then to bind mounts. Now ECS supports a native integration with ECS (both EC2 and Fargate) that will allow you to configure the tasks to mount the same file system (or Access Point) without even bothering about configuring EC2 (in fact it works with Fargate as well). See [this blog post series](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/developers-guide-to-using-amazon-efs-with-amazon-ecs-and-aws-fargate-part-1/) for more info.